# Missing Cookies in Android Browser

Tags: android, browser, cookies

I'm building a Cookie Base Login form for a Website.
But the Login doesn't work on any Tablet. The Cookies are missing on some Tablet's.

If I use an other Sim-Card it works. If i use Firefox to login it works to.

But the normal Browser loose the Cookies.
Any Idea what i can do?

Comment: Did you find out why cookies were missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CookieManager` to retreive cookie at some step, and then set it later:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
Cookie cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);

// .. and later

String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" +  cookie.getValue();
cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```